# Некорректная отправка файла через socket

Tags: java, tcp

Пытаюсь отправлять любой файл по TCP с моего клиента (на мобильном устройстве) на консольный сервер (на компьютере).
Подключение, отправка, получение, по-моему, происходят нормально, однако есть проблема с записью данных в файл.
Например, музыка в него записывается несколько раз, а у картинки записывается только одна "линия".
Я подозреваю, что проблема где-то в цикле, но не могу понять точно.

Код сервера, в котором происходит получение байтов из сокета и запись в файл:

```
String fileName;
int size;
try {
    size = sInput.readInt();
    fileName = sInput.readUTF();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\FileSenderDownload\\" + fileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        int receivedBytes = 0;
        while (true) {
            if (receivedBytes == -1)
                break;
            receivedBytes = input.read(buffer);
            System.out.println(receivedBytes);
            fos.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }
        System.out.println("Запись");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Код клиента для отправки файла:

```
try {
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream output= new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    output.writeInt((int)sendingFile.length());
    output.flush();
    System.out.println("File size" + sendingFile.length());
    output.writeUTF(sendingFile.getName());
    output.flush();
    System.out.println("File name" + sendingFile.getName());
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(sendingFile);
    int size = (int)sendingFile.length();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    int receivedBytes;
    while(true) {
        receivedBytes = input.read(buffer);
        if (receivedBytes == -1) {
            break;
        }
        if (receivedBytes > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
    input.close();
    out.close();
    socket.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Как исправить этот код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблемы в цикле `while (true)` на сервере:

1. `receivedBytes = input.read(buffer);` должно быть до проверки `if (receivedBytes == -1)`.
2. Нужно в `fos.write` указывать количество считанных байтов, а не длину буфера: `fos.write(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);`

В итоге цикл выглядит так:

```
while (true)
{
    receivedBytes = input.read(buffer);
    if (receivedBytes == -1)
        break;
    totalCount += receivedBytes;
    fos.write(buffer, 0, receivedBytes);
}
```

И по поводу кода в целом: использование `try-with-resources` и констант помогает улучшить код:

Клиент:

```
public void send(File sendingFile)
{
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, PORT);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(sendingFile))
    {
        output.writeInt((int)sendingFile.length());
        output.writeUTF(sendingFile.getName());
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int readCount;
        while ((readCount = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            output.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Сервер:

```
private void get(Socket socket)
{
    try (ObjectInputStream sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))
    {
        int size = sInput.readInt();
        String fileName = sInput.readUTF();
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILES_DIRECTORY + fileName))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int receivedBytes = 0;
            while (receivedBytes < size)
            {
                int readCount = sInput.read(buffer);
                if (readCount == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                receivedBytes += readCount;
                fos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Если через одно socket-соединение всегда будет передаваться только один файл, то на сервере можно не заморачиваться с подсчетом количества полученных байтов и сделать по аналогии с клиентом:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILES_DIRECTORY + fileName))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int readCount;
    while ((readCount = sInput.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }
}
```

---

При таком допущении код можно упростить ещё больше с использованием `Files.copy`:

Клиент:

```
public void send(File sendingFile)
{
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, PORT);
            ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))
    {
        output.writeUTF(sendingFile.getName());
        Path path = sendingFile.toPath();
        Files.copy(path, output);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Сервер:

```
private void get(Socket socket)
{
    try (ObjectInputStream sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))
    {
        String fileName = sInput.readUTF();
        Path path = Paths.get(FILES_DIRECTORY + fileName);
        Files.copy(sInput, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все действительно заработало) Жаль не могу рейтинг ответу повысить, но все равно благодарю.

Comment: @KostyaM на здоровье. Главное что ответ приняли. А плюсануть можно и потом (при достижении нужной репутации и при наличии желания в будущем)